# se puede hacer una conexion remota usando solo el app config?

Tags: c#

estoy interesado es hacer una conexion remota desde c# a sql server, pero solo por medio del app config, ya que si cambio mi clase conexion se me daña todo el proyecto y demore mas de un año en poder realizarlo. alguien podria ayudarme?
<

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Yo personalmente no entiendo tu pregunta. A que te refieres con realizar una conexión remota? Desde luego, el app.config es solo un archivo de configuración, no se puede "hacer nada" desde ahi. Pulsa en [edit]  y trata de explicar mejor tu problema. Un saludo.

Comment: Recordar que los Web.config App.Config con XML donde almacenamos configuraciones para los proyectos, puedes usar el TAG de connectionStrings para especificar tu conexión, en tu proyecto logicamente deberias de hacer referencia a esa conexión ya que desconozco cómo estes realizando actualmente tu conexión.

Comment: Hola Miguel. Has de leer los enlaces que te puso @Pikoh en su comentario para aprender como funcionan las preguntas aqui. Y recuerda no duplicar preguntas. Pulsa en "editar" par modificar la original y añadir la info que falta. Un saludo